# What should I do when two similar question was asked by two different accounts?

Tags: discussion, support

Today, I saw two very similar questions: [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70417183/assign-the-work-for-2-people-so-that-the-time-is-minimum) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70418540/find-a-way-to-assign-the-work-so-that-the-overall-time-is-minimum).

Both of these questions lead to a competitive programming problem on [this](http://lequydon.ntucoder.net/Problem/Details/6282) website, which later got discontinued, and got replaced by [this](https://lqdoj.edu.vn/) site.

Basically, this website is maintained by a teacher that teaches competitive programming in Vietnam.

As far as I know, the website has zero-tolerance against copying code from an outer source.

What should I do with these question?

Comment: _"As far as I know, the website has zero-tolerance against copying code from an outer source."_. That specific point is irrelevant in regards to SO. What matters is that if questions are on-topic, duplicates, or if there are indications of fraud/abuse.

Comment: Are you asking because the questions are similar (as the title implies) or because they refer to an external website (as the body implies)?

Comment: Personally, I would suggest that the fact that the 2 have an **identical** section in their attempts and format of the question is identical too it may well be the *same* person. Having 2 accounts isn't against the rules, many people do, however, these accounts aren't allowed to interact or be used to avoid limitations imposed on another (such as a question ban). You, I, nor any of the curators that use Meta have a way of validate if this is the case. The best you could do, if you feel that it is the same person (trying to avoid a ban) is raise a custom flag with as much evidence as possible.